# Force unmount of a device, how to?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I've mounted a block device (internal hard disk) to say `~/HD`, and I'm trying,

```
~# umount ~/HD
```

It answers,

```
umount: device is busy.
```

Now I kill all processes manually by examining

```
~# fuser -m ~/HD
```

I also make sure that really no process is accessing the `~/HD` path

```
~# lsof | grep HD
```

Still `umount ~/HD` says `device is busy` even with `-f` option.

PS: I don't want to use the `-l` option of `umount`, since the mounted device is actually an encrypted mapper device, which in turn won't get unmounted unless mapper device is clearly unmounted.

So basically my question is how to *really* force `umount` to unmount a device OR How can a device still be marked as *busy* while no processes are accessing it (or at least `fuser` and `lsof` don't report it) and what can I do about it?

I'm on Ubuntu 9.10 x64.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/73028

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will see this behavior if you have mounted something else on a subdirectory of ~/hd.  In this case, neither fuser nor lsof will show anything.  If you haven't mounted anything under ~/hd ('mount' will answer this question), then I'm not sure what to check.

Comment: I'm selecting your answer as best one, even this wasn't my condition but it may help others. Also, can't find any better answer. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Make sure your current working directory (run 'pwd') is not a under ~/hd. If you are currently in that directory, umount will refuse to unmount.

Answer (score 3):

Command **lsof** will tell you what process(es) hold a file open.

Answer (score 2):

to locate active processes/users execute:

> fuser -u /path/to/mount

then execute the following to remove them:

> fuser -k /path/to/mount

finally **umount** the offending device.

Comment: Dangerous. Use with `-M` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Larsks wrote:
"You will see this behavior if you have mounted something else on a subdirectory of ~/hd. In this case, neither fuser nor lsof will show anything."

Using lsof with grep will show subdirectory use - eg "lsof |grep HD".

I had the same problem as the original poster and found the cause using the command above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use **sync**?

The **sync** command flush the filesystem caches by force the changed blocks to be writed on the disk.

Comment: There is no need to sync -- umount will flush the cache as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to just unmount it, you can use **umount -f**

from *man umount* :

```
-f     Force unmount (in case of an unreachable NFS system).  (Requires kernel 2.1.116 or later.)
```

Comment: Doesn't work, but it is not your fault. It is Linus' fault. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't unmount because a user had an open SMB session. Worth checking.

Comment: This seems more like a comment then an answer to a 5 year old question.

Comment: i didnt have the rep, nor will i with downvotes, but does age matter when a post has ~21k views? This is where google lead me today and lsof | grep /mnt/disk solved my issue

Comment: Yes; it matters because comments are not answers.  You could easily edit your answer and make it an answer but currently how it is written seems more like a comment.  An answer describes a solution in detail and specifically answers the question that was asked.  You not having the reputation to post a comment as an answer isn't how you post a comment.

Comment: Sure I wanted to make it a comment but couldn't but you reference the fact it's 5 years old like it's important.  I will update it then... and add the ls grep part

Comment: All content is important.  Your answer brought this question to the 1st page. If you want to comment post helpful detailed content to questions you know the answer to or ask detailed specific questions

Comment: Especially the age of a post right?

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails do a

```
# umount -lf /unmountable_location
```

l for lazy, f for force